# How do I create pre-formatted Java files in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I am currently writing JUnit test cases using the Selenium-RC API.  I am writing my scripts like:

```
//example JUnit test case

public class myScripts extends SeleneseTestCase {

   public void setUp() throws Exception {
      SeleniumServer newSelServ = new SeleniumServer();
      newSelServ.start();
      setUp("https://mySite.com", "*firefox");
   }

   public void insert_Test_Name throws Exception {

       //write test code here

   }
}
```

And for each test, I have a new JUnit file.  Now, since the beginning of my JUnit files will all basically be the same, just with minor variations towards the end, I was thinking about creating a pre-formatted Java template to write create a file with the redundant code already written.  However, I can't find any information on whether this is possible.  Does Eclipse allow you to create file templates for certain packages?

Comment: Yes, you can create that template, but the advice to subclass is a better option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a super class to add all the common code. Creating template is really bad because of the fact you are duplicating the code at the end of the day.

```
class Super extends SeleneseTestCase{
// Add all common code
}

class Test1 extends Super{
   // only special test case logic

}
```

Also I would suggest not to create SeleniumServer instance for each test case, It will reduce overall performance of the test suite. You can reuse object as long as you are running test sequentially.

Comment: Thanks, works great!  Completely forgot about super classes, haha.  Testing all day creates bad habits :)  Will mark as answer when I can!

Comment: See, for your second point, I tried just creating each function as it's own test case under the same file, so I wouldn't have to set up the server each time.  But then I get an error about the socket on port 4444.  Is it possible to write multiple test functions under one class?